# jQuery if statements both firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following logic for an animated mobile site (optimised for the iphone) - 208 is the height before going full screen.

```
    var pageHeight = $(window).height();

    if (pageHeight == 320 ) {

        $('#slide3').animate({bottom: '0px',}, 3000, function() {$('.slide3Txt').animate({top:'30px'},500);godown3Pt2()});
    }
    if (pageHeight != 208) {

        $('#slide3').animate({bottom: '0px',}, 3000, function() {$('.slide3Txt').animate({top:'94px'},500);godown3Pt2()});

    }
```

my issue is that both events fire after each other on the iphone on lanscape orientation - any suggestions to improve this logic?

Comment: Maybe you want `else if`? Of course if the value is equal to `320` it is also different from `208`.

Comment: indeed - think i'm having a dozy afternoon! cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code it triggers if its not 208 and if it is 320, or just if its not 208

You need an `else if` so if its 320, it does the first animate if its anything else and not 208 it triggers the second animate

```
 var pageHeight = $(window).height();

    if (pageHeight == 320 ) {

        $('#slide3').animate({bottom: '0px',}, 3000, function() {$('.slide3Txt').animate({top:'30px'},500);godown3Pt2()});
    }else if (pageHeight != 208) {

        $('#slide3').animate({bottom: '0px',}, 3000, function() {$('.slide3Txt').animate({top:'94px'},500);godown3Pt2()});

    }
```